# Weird login message 20.04.4 LTS wants to upgrade to 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

What does this message mean?

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-124-generic x86_64)

 [unimportant stuff about documentation and system use]

0 updates can be applied immediately.

New release '22.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

lsb_realease -a reports:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

[edit]Solved, I can't read.[/edit]

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is the 2020-April release which is what you're using.  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the 2022-April release of Ubuntu, being two years newer.  The extra number shows the upgrade level (22.04.1 & 20.05.4 being current with .5 rolling out currently to *focal* or 20.04)

Comment: It is 20.04.04 that welcomes you. Not 22.04.04.

Comment: This message means literally what it says :) - informs you that a new LTS release of Ubuntu is available and you can upgrade to it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 is the 2020-April release which is what you're using.  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the 2022-April release of Ubuntu, being two years newer.

The extra number shows the upgrade level (*22.04.1 & 20.05.4 being current with .5 rolling out currently to focal or 20.04*).  The ISO release date for [20.04.5 is 1-September-2022](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule), but installed systems will display 20.04.5 ~a week before that date.  Even on release of 20.04.5; the important part (20.04 or *year.month* being 2020-April) does not change.

FYI:  At 20.04.5 the 20.04 system will get some benefits from the earlier 22.04 release, for example the 5.15 LTS kernel..  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS came out in April 2022, yet 20.04 users only got it recently, as part of the 20.04.5 upgrades (*where using the HWE kernel stack*)

Comment: Just FYI:  The 5.4 kernel you mention is the GA kernel stack for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  It remains the same (ie. 5.4 with only security fixes applied) for the life of the product (20.04).  An alternate HWE (*hardware enablement*) stack would have meant at 20.04.2 you upgraded to the 5.8 kernel from 20.10, at 20.04.3 you upgraded to 5.11 from 21.04, at 20.04.4 it upgraded to 5.13 from 21.10, and has already upgraded to the 5.15 from 22.04 as the current 20.04.5 upgrades roll out to existing *focal* or 20.04 users.  Servers default to using the *stable* GA kernel stack (ie. remain on 5.4)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have set your update manager to ' Notify me of a new Ubuntu version :
For long term Support versions. (22.04.1 point release)
Change this to ' never'  and run updates again, you will get 20.04.5 instead.